# while converting base64 to string getting system.Byte[]

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, base64

In an xml there is a tag  with below type

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:base64Binary" />
```

So in between `<attachment></attachment>` there is a base64 string

If I copy that string and do the below code it is successfully converting to a pdf file

```
string AsBase64String = "....." //base64 copied from xml file
byte[] tempBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(AsBase64String);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\d\hh.pdf", tempBytes);
```

Now when I read the xml file from my application all the nodes are getting assigned successfully except this attachment.

The code for assigning the attachment tag is as below

```
string Attach = dataRow2["Attachment"].ToString()
```

the value I am getting in `Attach` is `System.Byte[]`
not the string value between the tag.

Am I missing anything? Please help

Comment: going from strings to bytes never works.  use Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes().

Comment: @jdweng is it `string Attach = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataRow2["Attachment"])`

Comment: check DataTable to see if it is really a string.  A DataTable cell is an object that can contain any type.  Use this : byte[] Attach = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataRow2["Attachment"]). if this doesn't work change the encoding type UTF8 as required.

Comment: @jdweng `System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(char[]) has some invalid arguments` when im using `byte[] Attach = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataRow2["Attachment"])`

Comment: The data cell is not a string or character array.  Check what type data you have.  You can use this : string cellType = dataRow2["Attachment"].GetType().ToString();

Comment: @jdweng its giving me System.Byte[]

Comment: Then you don't need to use GetBytes() since it is already bytes.  No encoding is needed nor using String().  To read the data into a Base64 number use BitConverter().

Comment: @jdweng `byte[] Attach = BitConverter(dataRow2["Attachment"])` ?

Comment: @jdweng @jdweng `byte[] Attach = BitConverter(dataRow2["Attachment"])` ? it's not working..BitConverter.GetByte() also not working..

Comment: Bit convert you have to specify the data type like BitConvert.ToInt64(dataRow2["Attachment"], index).  Don't know which type will get you the expected results.  Index is an integer specifying where the first byte starts.  You can only convert one object at a time.  If you have an 8 byte type like Int64 then you have to increment the index by 8 each time you get the next value.